# Autorun script in cmd

Tags: cmd, autorun, program-structure

Somebody know how i can do a program with `autorun` script? I would like to do this in notepad with `extension .bat or .cmd`   for example `@echo off`

```
(and this autorun script)
```

Somebody can help me? I really need write this in notepad because recently I am learning coding and i am new in this.

Comment: "autorun" is not a thing of the file, but of how it is being started (for example the file is stored in the `startup` folder)

Comment: Do you know how can i do a script who will be transporting file in startup folder? In CMD of course or .bat or .cmd

Comment: `copy file.bat "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"`